# Disable swipe event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, swipe

using jquery mobile on swipe right it will show the next image..
however after swiping the last image it shows a blank page is there a way to disable swipe on last image?

also i set the width to 100% since i want it taking up the size of browser
but then i cant zoom anyway to enable zoom.

```js
$("img").on("swiperight", function () {
    $(this).hide().next().show('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 1000);
});

$("img").on("swipeleft", function () {
    $(this).hide().prev().show('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
 img {
     width: 100%;
 }

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mgottlieb/app/yom_rishon_jpeg/yr%20(1).jpg"/>

  <img class="hide" src="http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mgottlieb/app/yom_rishon_jpeg/yr%20(2).jpg"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9fxr3az/3/

Thanks